# No visible interface for selector - init method

Tags: ios, objective-c

That may sound odd, but please consider following:

```
-(instancetype)initWithModel:(FRPPhotoModel *)photoModel{

    self = [super initWithModel:photoModel];


    if (!self) return nil;

   // a lot of code here

    return self;

}
```

Actually it underline as error following line:

```
 self = [super initWithModel:photoModel];
```

Error is: No visible @interface for 'RVMViewModel' declares the selector 'initWithModel:'

It actually reference to same method it declared is. Of course, superclass does not know about it. But, in a book im reading following work fine (that is the same method:

```
-(instancetype)initWithModel:(FRPPhotoModel *)photoModel {
    self = [super initWithModel:photoModel];
    if (!self) return nil;

    @weakify(self);
    [self.didBecomeActiveSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        @strongify(self);
        [self downloadPhotoModelDetails];
    }];

    RAC(self, photoImage) = [RACObserve(self.model, fullsizedData) map:^id(id value) {
        return [UIImage imageWithData:value];
    }];

    return self;
}
```

It work perfectly fine. How to fix that?

Comment: What is the `super` class of that class?

Comment: @trojanfoe RVMViewModel

Comment: And that method exists in the `super` class?

Comment: @trojanfoe no, because it custom initializer. However, in a book i read the same method work fine. RVMViewModel is class from ReactiveCocoa library :))

Comment: So shouldn't that just be `self = [super init];`?

Comment: @trojanfoe i guess so. Dont know why author use that approach, i just follow tutorial )

Comment: googling `FRPPhotoModel` gives https://github.com/ashfurrow/FunctionalReactivePixels, which uses its own version of `ReactiveViewModel`.

Comment: @Kreiri ok, thats answer my question, thanks!